# How to save the model after 1000 epoches and determine which GPU is used?

Tags: python, python-2.7, model, keras

I am trying to run the following program. It works fine, but it is saving every epoch and not the best one. I want to save the model file after `1000 epoches` as I am running `10000` epoches.  Also I have 2 GPU in my system and want to know which one is working for my training

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as numpy
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, LeakyReLU, PReLU
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.callbacks import CSVLogger, ModelCheckpoint
import h5py
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session


# Make the program use only one GPU
os.environ['CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER'] = 'PCI_BUS_ID'
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '1'
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
set_session(tf.Session(config=config))


with h5py.File(''.join(['test2015to2017_close.h5']), 'r') as hf:
    datas = hf['inputs'].value
    labels = hf['outputs'].value


output_file_name='test2015to2017_close_CNN_2_relu'

step_size = datas.shape[1]
batch_size= 8
nb_features = datas.shape[2]

epochs = 10000

#split training validation
training_size = int(0.8* datas.shape[0])
training_datas = datas[:training_size,:]
training_labels = labels[:training_size,:]
validation_datas = datas[training_size:,:]
validation_labels = labels[training_size:,:]
#build model

# 2 layers
model = Sequential()


model.add(Conv1D(activation='relu', input_shape=(step_size, nb_features), strides=3, filters=8, kernel_size=20))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv1D( strides=4, filters=nb_features, kernel_size=16))

'''
# 3 Layers
model.add(Conv1D(activation='relu', input_shape=(step_size, nb_features), strides=3, filters=8, kernel_size=8))
#model.add(LeakyReLU())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv1D(activation='relu', strides=2, filters=8, kernel_size=8))
#model.add(LeakyReLU())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv1D( strides=2, filters=nb_features, kernel_size=8))
# 4 layers
model.add(Conv1D(activation='relu', input_shape=(step_size, nb_features), strides=2, filters=8, kernel_size=2))
#model.add(LeakyReLU())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv1D(activation='relu', strides=2, filters=8, kernel_size=2))
#model.add(LeakyReLU())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv1D(activation='relu', strides=2, filters=8, kernel_size=2))
#model.add(LeakyReLU())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv1D( strides=2, filters=nb_features, kernel_size=2))
'''

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(training_datas, training_labels,verbose=1, batch_size=batch_size,validation_data=(validation_datas,validation_labels), epochs = epochs, callbacks=[CSVLogger(output_file_name+'.csv', append=True),ModelCheckpoint('weights/'+output_file_name+'-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.5f}.hdf5', monitor='val_loss', verbose=1,mode='min')])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save model at a given epoch, you can create a [callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#create-a-callback):

```
class SaveAtEpoch(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, target):
        super().__init__()
        self.target = target

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        if epoch == self.target:
            self.model.save('model_at_epoch_%d.h5' % self.target)
...
model.fit(..., callbacks=[SaveAtEpoch(1000)])
```

To specify which gpu to use you can use [tf.device](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#device):

```
with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
    model = Sequential()
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ModelCheckpoint https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint to save the best model while training if instead, you want to save only after 1k epoch I would simply train the model for 1k epochs and then call model.save('model.h5')